# Android Tutorial Causes Render Problem When Adding Image

Tags: android, image

I am working through the Android development tutorial called "Android Basics With Compose" on section "First Android App" > "Basic Layout" > part 4 "Add images to your Android app" > section 3 "Add an image composable" (https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3). I've downloaded the "android.party" png and -- to my understanding -- successfully imported it so that I can see it in my "res > drawable" directory where the tutorial says it should be. I've successfully reproduced everything in the tutorial up to this point.

This issue begins when I start following the instructions to make that picture the background. Once I create the Image composable as instructed and call it in the preview, the preview no longer renders, telling me "Some issues were fond while trying to render this preview".

My code in "java > com.example.happybirthday > ui.theme > MainActivity.kt":

```
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    GreetingText(message = "Happy Birthday Sam!", from = "From Emma")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 116.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.End)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Image(
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun BirthdayCardPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        GreetingImage(message = "Happy Birthday Sam!", from = "From Emma")
    }
}
```

Stack Trace for "Render problem":

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: androidparty   at com.example.happybirthday.MainActivityKt.GreetingImage(MainActivity.kt:65)   at com.example.happybirthday.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-4$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:76)   at com.example.happybirthday.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-4$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:75)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)   at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)   at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)   at com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.ThemeKt.HappyBirthdayTheme(Theme.kt:65)   at com.example.happybirthday.MainActivityKt.BirthdayCardPreview(MainActivity.kt:75)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposableMethod(ComposableInvoker.kt:155)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable(ComposableInvoker.kt:195)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:711)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:709)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:746)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:704)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:61)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:651)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:650)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:645)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:135)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:704)   at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:701)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:404)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:250)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:249)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)   at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)   at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)   at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3173)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:950)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1060)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1147)   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21291)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3491)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)   at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:58)
```

I am completely new to Android development and using Android Studio, so I naively thought that this was an issue related to my having a newer version of Android Studio (Hedgehog; 2023.1.1) since I believe the tutorial was made with the Flamingo version (2022.2.1). Sure enough, uninstalling the new version and reinstalling the old one did not fix anything.

I really don't know what I could be doing differently than the tutorial, but surely I am doing something strange, and I'll gladly share any minute details that could be clues. Copying the all the code directly from this part's section 9 "Get the solution code" does not fix anything, so it's presumably not in that step. I'm on Windows 10.

Thank you!

Comment: First, try building the project with the picture you have. If it's still not working, try using different, lower-quality images – that might help.

Comment: Thank you @Abdo21, re-building did the trick. Thank you for answering a beginner's question!